# Get previous cell value + side cell value calculation in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, window-functions

[image]

I wan this type of calculated date value in SQL.

Is any way to get this type of calculated data ?

Comment: Edit the qestion add expected result too.

Comment: @Roank1112 . . . Your question has no information on what you are trying to calculate.

Comment: In "Date" column i have fix date for first row. Now i wan to get value in "Date" column  from previous cell of  "Date" + duration.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you want:

```
select
    t.*,
    dateadd(
        day, 
        sum(t.duration) over(order by autoid), 
        first_value(t.date) over(order by autoid)
    ) date
from mytable t
```

Starting from the first value in the `date` column (which, as I understand, is the only non-`null` value in that column), this incrementally adds the number of days in the `duration` column.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want the cumulative duration.  I would do this just by subtracting the earliest:

```
select t.*,
       datediff(day, min(date) over (), date) as total_duration
from t;
```